# Android GridLayout: How to align child view to right with its column width proportional

Tags: java, android, android-gridlayout

I have a Grid with two columns, each with a label. I want the label on the 2nd column to align to the right:

```
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    app:columnCount="2">

    <TextView
        android:text="Cell 0"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Cell 1"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#0000FF"/>

</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

[image]

How can I make the 1st column to be **equal** to the 2nd column, like in the mockup below?

[image]

I tried setting `android:gravity="right"` but it solves half of the problem. Columns are equal in width, but the blue label fills the column:

```
        <TextView
            android:text="Cell 1"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="#0000FF"/>
```

[image]

The way GridLayout computes the width of a proportionally sized column is very weird. It appears it takes into account the width of the child view. The documentation does not help in describing how the `layout_columnWeight` works exactly.

Comment: try `android:gravity="right"` instead `app:layout_gravity="right"`

Comment: @Omkar thanks but it does not produce the result I'm expecting. The two columns are equal but the blue `TextView` fills the column horizontally. I need it to stay aligned to the right.

Comment: @Omkar Why "3" and not "4" ?  :)

Answer (score 0):

try below code this may result what you expected

```
 <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    app:columnCount="2"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:text="Cell 0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="right">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cell 1"
            android:background="#0000FF"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there a way without a wrapping LinearLayout? It makes the layout a lot more complicated if I do this in all the places in the UI.

Comment: Thanks again but if you play with the `android:text` on the blue label to a bigger string like `android:text="Cell 1 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" you can see how the columns do not have the same width anymore, the width of the 1st column is decreased.

Comment: I'm confused how something this simple it's so hard to do. Maybe it's because I don't have enough experience.

Comment: add  `android:layout_width="0dp"` to grid items.... check updated code. Hope this work for you

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking for a solution which use any wrapping view.